# How we can get "get_post_meta" of specific user who added it

Tags: post-meta

Basically i have front end form which store the notes and tags of post. And every user who logged in can store there own notes and tags. But i want when he view the notes and tags he can only see here own notes and tags not all the notes and tags of every one.

For example there are 100 post there. Every user have an option to save notes and tags of each post and no one other can be able to see there notes and tags. so when user logged in he can able to view there notes and tags which he added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this you can either generate metakey value for [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) in such a way that it will contain user id.

```
//Example :
global $user_ID,$post_ID;
// Store the values
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'meta_key'.$user_ID, '$meta_value');
// Get the values
$meta_values = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'meta_key'.$user_ID);
```

or you can save it in user meta as following

```
//Example :
global $user_ID,$post_ID;
// Store the values
update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'meta_key'.$post_ID, 'meta_value' );
// Get the values
$meta_values = get_usermeta( $user_ID, 'meta_key'.$post_ID );
```